# How Google Ads headlines and descriptions work?

Tags: google-ads

It says I need five headlines. If I try to add less I get the error message:

> Too few elements in the collection.

Does Google switch out between the headlines? What if I'd rather it just use one headline for all ads? I tried to copy/paste the same headline 5 times and got an error about duplicates existing.

I looked at another existent campaign on my website and that campaign appears to have 3 duplicate headlines (not 5). Is that campaign just kinda being grandfathered in?

And what if I wanted certain headlines to go with certain descriptions? From the user interface, there doesn't appear to be a way to link the two.

Finally, does the order of the headlines/descriptions matter?